# How to delete columns that have 1 unique variable in a loop?

Tags: r, loops

Here is what I have thus far:

```
  testdf=olddf;

for (i in colnames(testdf))

  if (length(unique(testdf[,i]))==1){

    testdf[,-(i)]

    }
```

I cannot make the aforementioned code work. Could someone assist in advising what I am doing incorrectly? Essentially, I am trying to make a loop in a way such that each column is checked to ensure there is no data that is unique. For instance if column length is equal 1 it must be deleted.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, it is best to avoid for loops if you can. Not that they should be avoided all together, but vectorized operations tend to be quicker. In this instance, `sapply` is your friend.

```
df = data.frame(v1=sample(letters, 10), v2=sample(1:100, 10), v3=4, v4=sample(LETTERS, 10))
x = sapply(names(df), function(x) length(unique(df[[x]])) > 1)
df[, x]
#    v1 v2 v4
# 1   e 82  P
# 2   i 45  T
# 3   z 76  W
# 4   u 27  Y
# 5   n  2  Q
# 6   x 72  B
# 7   o 61  O
# 8   d 47  R
# 9   s 42  G
# 10  k 66  S
```

## Update (based on conversation in comments)

```
# This line of code identifies the columns that are both numeric
# and have values where max != min
good_cols = sapply(testdf, function(x) {
    is.numeric(x) && ((max(x) - min(x)) > 0)
})

# Subset the original data to just the good columns for modeling
model_df = testdf[, good_cols]

# Run the regression
lm(y ~ ., data = model_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use - operator to index a character column name. One approach would be using which. This should work in your case.

```
for (i in colnames(testdf)) {
  if (length(unique(testdf[,i])) == 1) {
    testdf<- testdf[,-which(colnames(testdf) == i) ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Never mind it worked! I had a small bracket in wrong place! Thank you!

Comment: Another question if you don't mind. Since I removed all issues with data, when I try to run a regression on the cleaned data, I am still getting the following error:

`Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`

Do you know what else it could be? All my data is numericals

Answer (score 0):

On a high level, for this to work you would need to reassign the `testdf` variable. Currently you just select it. i.e, replace `testdf[, -(i)]` with `testdf <- testdf[, -(i)]`.

Also, you iterate through names, and you can't use the `-` operator in brackets to de-select a specific name. You could use indices, though, however if you do use indices and you re-assign `testdf` in the for-loop, you'll likely remove columns of the for loop and end up trying to refer to an index that no longer exists in `testdf`.

I would suggest using `dplyr` selector functions (see `?select_if`) that would help here. See example below:

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 6)
temp %>% select_if(~length(unique(.)) > 1)
   mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 21.4 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4 18.1 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
5 19.2 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6 17.8 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7 19.7 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response Zack. When I run the following:

`testdf= olddf;

for (i in 1:dim(test2)[2])
  
  if (length(unique(test2[,i]))==1){
    
    testdf=testdf[,i]
  
    }`

I get the following error:
`Error in `[.data.frame`(testdf, , i) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: What is likely happening is along the lines of what i mentioned when you remove the column in the for loop. You'll end up decreasing the width of your data.frame, and when you get far enough through your loop, you try to refer to a column index that no longer exists.

Comment: Anyway to fix my initial code? I tried your dplyr but it wont work for me.